# Using Tauri Rust commands to enable server-side rendering in Next.js and dynamically render components with Chakra UI and React

Tags: reactjs, api, rust, next.js, tauri

Using ServerSideRendering Nextjs features to loop a component using Tauri, Chakraui, Reactjs and Next.js.
At the moment I build the app using Tauri, the rendering of the page isn't working as there's no Server render and it's only static, how can I use the Tauri rust commands to save the data from inputs and use it to render x times a component through a loop

```
<main>
            {Array.from({length: key.length}, (_,i) => i+1).map((vars) =>( 
                <div key={vars}>
                    <Card padding={2} marginBottom={"2"}>
                        <Text  marginTop={2} fontWeight={"semibold"}></Text>
                        <Text  marginBottom={"1"}></Text>
                        <Text ></Text>
                        <Text ></Text>
                        <Text ></Text>
                        <Text ></Text>
                        <Text ></Text>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            ))}
            
</main>
```

I use Nextjs apis to get the keys, but when I run the build app there's no rendering of the components, how can I implement a rust command to save and access values then use them in the jsx and implement render-in-time after the compilation.